# use next_day and to_date in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Friends..

I'm trying to use next_day and to_date function in the where clause but not able to make it working..

Rows are in millions so trying to avoid trunc in the statement for better query performance and also to use index... this is in Oracle 11g

Basically, select query deducts 90 days from the input date and display first available Sunday in the last 7 days.

Date (20140203) & 90 are the input parameters so it can vary...

```
SELECT  next_day((to_date(20140203, 'yyyymmdd') - 90, 'DAY') -7, 'SUNDAY')
FROM DUAL;
```

I have tried different variations for couple of hours but just not able to figure this out.

thanks for reading this...

Comment: can you post an example please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  next_day(((to_date(20140203, 'yyyymmdd') - 90) -7), 'SUNDAY')
FROM DUAL;
```

I don't know what the `'DAY'` was doing in the query.

Comment: Gordon.... that was perfect and worked in the first try ... I will accept this answer in 6 mins.. it's not allowing me currently...